# Can I set roledefs for Fabric in .fabricrc?

Tags: python, fabric

My hosts are pretty static and I was hoping I could just set them in the .fabricrc, rather than define them in the individual fabfiles. Is this possible? I've not had luck making it work.

I have multiple roles I'd like to define (test, staging, prod) and I tried something like this  in .fabricrc:

```
roledefs = {
    'staging': ['foo1', 'foo2', 'foo3'],
    'prod': ['bar1', 'bar2']
}
```

But that doesn't seem to get picked up, I get an error that the role is not found when I try to use it. I also tried just setting one like this:

```
roledefs['test'] = ['foo']
```

And got the same result.

Is this possible? Like I said, I know how to do it in the fabfiles themselves and I can go that route, but I'd rather not have to set them there.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Going from the [docs about the fabricrc](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.9/usage/fab.html#settings-files) this is too complex. You can though just leverage the fact that it's python and import a python file from some shared location. So something like this:

`from .. import global_fabfile`

Or any other normal python way to import python files.